# error CS1729: The type `ARSoft.Tools.Net.Dns.DnsServer' does not contain a constructor that takes `4' arguments

Tags: c#, github, visual-studio-2013, dns, syntax-error

I'm trying to compile a code taken from github.
My understanding of Visual Studio or C# is pretty basic. Can anybody please help me with the error?

Github source:
github.com/slothbag/NxtHypeDns

Source file link:
github.com/slothbag/NxtHypeDns/blob/master/NxtHypeDns/Program.cs

Error screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/McQXa.jpg

Thanks

Comment: The error is pretty clear. It says there is no constructor for DnsServer thats takes 4 arguments. Did you look into DnsServer's constructors? Also check with the owner of the repo.

Comment: Might seems pretty clear to you as C# dev. To me, I'm lost what I need to fix. I'm not so good with C# or coding. Very basic. Yes, I contacted the owner on NXT Forums where he posted it. Haven't heard back since friday-saturday. :(

Comment: @satinder It will be difficult to explain what is wrong if you don't know what a constructor, arguments or constructor overloading are. If you *do* know what those things are (or look them up), the problem should become obvious to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The code here](https://github.com/LETO-R/ARSoft.Tools.Net/blob/master/ARSoft.Tools.Net/Dns/DnsServer.cs) looks like the DnsServer takes those 4 arguments. Are you sure you have the correct binaries? How did you install?

If you are using the [codeplex version](http://arsofttoolsnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets?branch=master) then it doesn't look like it take a ProcessQuery parameter.

Comment: Hi Mark, I installed it using Nugget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ARSoft.Tools.Net

Comment: So you're using the codeplex version. Try removing the ProcessQuery parameter from your `new DnsServer(....` line

Comment: Awesome! I changed the line to:
`var server = new DnsServer(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1053), 10, 10);`

and it compiled the build. Do you think it should work fine? I'll need to run it on Linux through Mono. Will try it later today, and see if it works.

There are bunch of files there in "NxtHypeDns-master\NxtHypeDns\bin\Release", so I assume I'll have to copy the whole folder in Linux to run the exe. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks again! :)